# Gitlab.rb parameters to change nginx.conf or gitlab-http.conf

Tags: nginx, configuration, gitlab

Does anyone know a method of changing parameters in either nginx.conf or gitlab-http.conf through gitlab.rb.

Both files say:  "To change the contents below, edit /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb" but I don't know what parameters to use to change these!

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 2):

What exact parameter to you want to change?

If you want to change the "HTTP port", you can set in the /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb like this

```
external_url = "http://<somepath>:8000"
```

And this page https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md#configuration has quite a lot of information about the gitlab.rb

Answer (score 2):

You can get a full list of options on the https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/files/gitlab-config-template/gitlab.rb.template

Answer (score 0):

Well i had the same problem i did this:

```
touch /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
chmod 0600 touch /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
```

and added

```
listen "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port", :tcp_nopush => true
```

for example.